# API Gateway in GKE with Authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, microservices, api-gateway, gke-networking

For microservices running in GKE of Google Cloud Platform, how to create a API gateway that handles:

- Expose services externally and redirect to services: Works like Ingress that each service does not have to expose itself but instead only one API gateway
- Authentication: Before any traffics redirected to services, it is authenticated by API gateway

I have searched and found Google Cloud Endpoint and Ambassador, but they sort of lack instruction for GKE. Any good tutorials on them would be also appreciated

Thank you!

Update development:

- Google Cloud Endpoint turns out to be a side-car container in front of the API service application container, which is basically service mesh. According to this guide: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/architecture-overview#esp

So the question again, how to set up API Gateway for GKE?

Comment: Is this the tutorial for [Endpoints with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine) you were missing?

Comment: I've tried it but got stuck at Send the request. It says curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.228.130.177 port 80: Connection refused

Anyhow, if it works, will you use deployment.yaml as an example to every manifest of each service?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please reserve some time to read [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I encourage you to edit your question with a practical example of architecture you want to deploy, the steps you did and list the issue you had Sending the Request to the API gateway and any other issue you face in your deployment, this way you will get a better answer and will enable others with similar issues to be helped as well.

Comment: Hi thank you @willrof

That is figured out. Although, openAPI is challenging to register new API. For example, how to add /sendEmail endpoint to openapi.yaml file. Is there any tool to config it?